# How do I find out which base fields are available for an entity type?

Tags: entities, 8

If I have an entity type id as a string, how I can tell which base fields are defined for that entity type?

For example, how do I programatically check that an entity type has the "changed" field?

Comment: Note that entity keys might have a different field name. For example the id key of nodes is named nid.

Answer (score 6):

How to get the base fields for an entity type id:

```
$base_fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id);
```

You get an array. The keys are the field names. Example how to loop through this array:

```
foreach ( $base_fields as $field_name => $definition ) {
  echo "$field_name: ", $definition->getDescription(), "\n";
}
```

**Edit:**

The method has moved to the service `EntityFieldManager`:

```
$base_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')
  ->getBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id);
```

Comment: EntityManager is deprecated

Comment: EntityManager is used 2500 times in core. For me it seems ok to use it.

Comment: When something is marked as deprecated it means it is going to be removed in future versions. If you want to future proof your code then avoid deprecated methods and classes. There is an alternative method in the description.

Comment: But for now there are a lot of things you can only do with EntityManager. This will take some time until it will get obsolete. As long as core uses it, I will do the same. Which is the alternative method? Please provide the code.

Comment: The methods in entity manager are all synthetic sugar to the new implantations. They exist only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Sorry, that's actually a mistake, it should be entityTypeManager, fixed up now.
EDIT: Woops, it's early, wrong answer.

Comment: @Eyal, found it, this is now in EntityFieldManager, see updated code in answer.

Comment: Nice find @4k4. However, I'm on 8.0.4 and can't see the function \Drupal::entityFieldManager, I have the service though.

Comment: As said before, it's early and we don't know how core will use it. But you can try to get the service: `$container->get('entity_field.manager')->getBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is through the entity type manager service, by getting the entity type definition and class:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$container = \Drupal::getContainer();
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager */
$entity_type_manager = $container->get('entity_type.manager');
$entity_type_definition = $entity_type_manager->getDefinition($entity_type);
$entity_type_class = $entity_type_definition->getClass();
$fields = call_user_func([$entity_type_class, 'baseFieldDefinitions'], $entity_type_definition);
if (!empty($fields['changed'])) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Comment: You can get the entity type manager directly from \Drupal by using the entityTypeManager method. `\Drupal->entityTypeManager()`

Comment: Yes, but usually you'd dependency inject either the container or the entityTypeManager service into your service.

Comment: Do you know what is the best practice in dependency injection? Container or multiple devices? (I have used the second option)

Comment: @Eyal I inject each individual service as that makes more sense from a class depending on something. It also means you can swap those things out easily without changing implementation code and makes unit testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the class of the entity type then:

```
$fields = Foo::baseFieldDefinitions(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('foo'));
```

Comment: This was specifically how to get it from a string id. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for `drush`, sample `$entity_type_id` is `user` but could be `node` etc..

```
drush ev 'var_export(array_keys(\Drupal::service("entity_field.manager")->getBaseFieldDefinitions("user")))'
```